# Java EE + Hibernate + Glassfish 3.1 + MySQL 5.5.16 -> utf doesn't work

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, utf-8, glassfish

I can't get the hibernate to write utf8 chars to database. If I manually write them using phpmyadmin or similar tools it gets displayed in web and everything is ok. But if I mannualy fill form and submit it, then use hibernate to save it to DB it gives `Ä¯Å³ÄÅ³Ä`. Everything in MySQL is utf-8:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';
+----------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value             |
+----------------------+-------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci   |
| collation_database   | utf8_general_ci   |
| collation_server     | utf8_general_ci   |
+----------------------+-------------------+

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       | 
| character_set_connection | utf8                       | 
| character_set_database   | utf8                       | 
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     | 
| character_set_results    | utf8                       | 
| character_set_server     | utf8                       | 
| character_set_system     | utf8                       | 
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ | 
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

All tables/columns in varchar tables are `utf-8 general`.

My hibernate-config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
      ">

    <!-- Enable annotation style of managing transactions -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" /> 

    <!-- Declare the Hibernate SessionFactory for retrieving Hibernate sessions -->
    <!-- See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/annotation/AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.html -->       
    <!-- See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/index.html?org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html -->
    <!-- See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/index.html?org/hibernate/Session.html -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"> <!-- init-method="createDatabaseSchema" -->
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="lt.database.model" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>                
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities--> 
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close"
    p:driverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    p:jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost/aukcionas?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"
    p:user="root"
    p:password=""
    p:acquireIncrement="5"
    p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60"
    p:maxPoolSize="100"
    p:maxStatements="50"
    p:minPoolSize="10" />

    <!-- Declare a transaction manager-->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"
          p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />

</beans>
```

So WHY i still can't get this thing to work? I use:

- GlassFish 3.1
- MySQL 5.5.16
- Hibernate 3
- Spring 3.0.2
- Spring Security 3.0.7

Comment: Are you sure the correct value is being passed to hibernate - have you logged the value just before calling the hibernate API to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by myself. Add this to web.xml file:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```